# ffmpeg concat doesn't work with absolute path

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to use concat with absolute path, but it doesn't seem to work.  In the doc it says it should work.  Anyone have an idea how to make it work?
[ffmpeg Doc](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files)

It doesn't work because it seem to append the text file directory to the file path

```
Impossible to open 'C:/temp/ffmpeg/c:/temp/ffmpeg/01.mov'
```

I use Windows 7.

```
ffmpegTest.txt:
file 'c:/temp/ffmpeg/01.mov'
file 'c:/temp/ffmpeg/02.mov'

"Y:/Shotgun/bin/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe" -f concat -i "C:/temp/ffmpeg/ffmpegTest.txt" -c copy "C:/temp/ffmpeg/test.mov
ffmpeg version N-58949-g0e575c2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec  9 2013 22:06:49 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 58.100 / 52. 58.100
  libavcodec     55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
  libavformat    55. 22.100 / 55. 22.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     3. 92.100 /  3. 92.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[concat @ 0000000000337920] Impossible to open 'C:/temp/ffmpeg/c:/temp/ffmpeg/01.mov'
C:/temp/ffmpeg/ffmpegTest.txt: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 22):

I just ran into similar error messages. I eventually figured it out. There were two issues.

**Issue 1:**

When doing

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <path_to_text_file> ...
```

the `path_to_text_file` must use forward slashes, not backslashes, even in Windows. This rule doesn't seem to apply for the video file paths on the command line though -- only for the text file path on the command line.

**Issue 2:**

The paths listed within your text file are interpreted by ffmpeg as being relative to the location of your text file. (In particular, the paths listed are not relative to the current working directory.)

Thus, for example, if the video files you're trying to concatenate together are in the same directory as your text file (but different than the current working directory), then the paths listed in your text file should simply be the video file names without any preceding directories.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: *The paths listed within your text file are interpreted by ffmpeg as being relative to the location of your text file.* There is a bug in ffmpeg under windows, which is highlighted in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1374679/598963)

Answer (score 15):

With the current version of ffmpeg (May 10 2020), on Windows 10, the list file must contain the ffmpeg form of a file URL.  Using the OP's list file, the contents of it would need to be:

```
file 'file:c:/temp/ffmpeg/01.mov'
file 'file:c:/temp/ffmpeg/02.mov'
```

`-safe 0` is still required

See also https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2702

Comment: I guess this is the only correct answer to keep absolute paths for both list file and the source files inside it. Thanks.

Comment: Use CMD to generate absolute path configuration file on Windows `(for %i in (*.ts) do @echo file 'file:%cd%\%i') > mylist.txt`

Comment: The single quotes in your example are also essential, I tried it with double quotes and it wouldn't work. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This needs to be upvoted to the high heavens.

Comment: Will this also work on linux?

Answer (score 4):

[@Eric's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1259960/598963) provides an important instruction to allow full paths in the concat demuxer input (you must provide the `-safe 0` option to ffmpeg). However, under Windows, ffmpeg's concat demuxer doesn't correctly handle *absolute/full paths **starting with the disk name***. Though it correctly recognizes full paths in its security checks, it misinterprets such paths as relative (because they don't start with a slash) when opening the file. Since non-absolute paths are relative to the location of the concat demuxer input script, `ffmpeg` prepends the path of the latter to the file path. If the concat script command line argument doesn't contain any file path separators (i.e. is a just a filename) the problem is masked.

Illustration:

```
concat.txt:
file 'c:/videos/01.flv'
file 'c:/videos/02.flv'


ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "C:/temp/concat.txt" -c copy "C:/temp/test.flv"
...
[concat @ 0000000000abcdef] Impossible to open 'C:/temp/c:/videos/01.flv'
C:/temp/concat.txt: Invalid argument


cd C:\temp
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "./concat.txt" -c copy "C:/temp/test.flv"
...
[concat @ 0000000000abcdef] Impossible to open './c:/videos/01.flv'
./concat.txt: Invalid argument


ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "concat.txt" -c copy "C:/temp/test.flv"
# Works successfully!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can **either** use a text file that is a list of input files like so:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i ffmpegTest.txt -c:v copy output.mov
```

**OR**

You can explicitly name the files like so:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i 'c:/temp/ffmpeg/01.mov' -i 'c:/temp/ffmpeg/02.mov' -c:v copy 'C:/temp/ffmpeg/output.mov'
```

Note that you use 2 inputs one after another, and then use `-c:v copy` to say that there should be no re-encoding- only joining. Also, this is the concat **demuxer**. This is flexible, but does require the 2 input files to have same codecs.

The content of the text file is as you wrote:

```
file 'c:/temp/ffmpeg/01.mov'
file 'c:/temp/ffmpeg/02.mov'
```

**Note the single quotes**

The generic format is:

```
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

That would apply to multiple drives and paths.

Here is a **real** example of a concatenation file that works:

```
file '/run/media/rnx/New Volume1/PREMIER_OUTPUTEST/Sequence004.mpeg'
file '/home/rnx/Sequence003.mpeg'
file '/run/user/rnx/gvfs/users on edtmchn/Public/Sequence01.mpeg'
```

This is across :
One internal drive
One external USB Drive
One Network drive on another windows machine on the same domain

The command use is :

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i conc.txt -c:v copy -strict -2 output.mpeg
```

This works as expected without any errors.

Comment: I need to use a file since I can have a lot of video.  And I need absolute path in the file

Comment: I can't, the file are on a network drive and in multiple folder.  I can't force a specific directory

Comment: I have this error with absolute path:  Impossible to open 'C:/temp/ffmpeg/c:/temp/ffmpeg/01.mov'

Comment: You are getting the error because you command is wrong. See the answer.

Comment: It doesn't work for absolute path.  It only work if the file are at the same place of the text file.

Comment: I added in my question that I'm on Windows.  It's probably related to the path formatting if your example work and mine doesn't

Comment: Try with single quotes. And on windows forward slashes become back-slashes.

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried blackslash/slash too :(

Comment: This answer works on ffmpeg version N-90173, Win10, CMD prompt only if the -i parameter does NOT have single quotes and does NOT use forward slashes:  

-i C:\foo\bar\filelist.txt

Comment: @JayBorseth this is for Linux. Forward slashes, /run/ folder, /home/ folder are typical of Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Notice; on Windows, if you are using concat with a textfile, the paths in the textfile need to be **relative to the output path**.

E.g.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i file.txt "C:\foo\file.mp4"
```

If your files are located in the directory `C:\temp\bar.mp4` your textfile looks like this:

```
file ..\temp\bar.mp4
...
```

Comment: Missing `"` character?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg.exe" -f concat -safe 0 -i fileWithAbsoluePaths.txt -c copy out.mov
```

In your case

```
"Y:/Shotgun/bin/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe" -f concat -safe 0 -i "C:/temp/ffmpeg/ffmpegTest.txt" -c copy "C:/temp/ffmpeg/test.mov
```

The key is **-safe 0**. That allows you to put absolute paths in the txt file.

Comment: Under windows there is a caveat that is covered in my answer: https://superuser.com/a/1374679/598963

Answer (score 1):

**There are 4 common types of path in FFMPEG:**

1. Absolute Windows path e.g. `C:\Users\you\file.mp4`.
2. Relative Windows path e.g. `..\..\file.mp4`.
3. Absolute UNIX path e.g. `/home/you/file.mp4`.
4. Relative UNIX path e.g. `../../file.mp4`.

---

**When running on Windows:**

> Tested on FFMPEG `4.1` & `5.0`.

- Use Absolute Windows path for `-i`.
- Use Absolute Windows path for output.
- Use Absolute UNIX path for file entry e.g. `file /C/Users/you/file.mp4`.

**Example**

```bash
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i C:\Users\you\videos.txt -c copy C:\Users\you\output.mp4
```

**`videos.txt`**

```
file '/C/Users/you/video-1.mp4'
file '/C/Users/you/video-2.mp4'
file '/C/Users/you/video-3.mp4'
```

---

**The `file <path>` entry rules when using `-i` option:**

**With *single-quote*:**

Escape *single-quote* characters in the `path` using *backslash*.

```
file '/video \'Hello world\'.mp4'
```

**Without *single-quote*:**

Escape *whitespace* and *backslash* characters in the `path` using *backslash*.

```
file /video\ 'Hello\ world'.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

While `cmd.exe` is case-insensitive, `ffmpeg` isn't (being built primarily on linux, it tends towards *nix shell conventions). If you change the `c:` on each line of your input file to `C:`, it should work, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move text & binaries to same directory so I don't have to include paths to binaries when `concat`ing.

The forward slash `/` instead of backslash `\` technique seems to work with ffmpeg, although I've wasted half a day of debugging before coming to this post, which rectified the problem in seconds.

I can go back to old code where there's no need to move files & `cd` everytime to `concat`.

Tested on Win 10