# Get error while adding subtitles with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to add a SubRip to mp4 videos but get error. Here is my command:

`ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\wwy12\Downloads\RaymondChen20_high.mp4" -s 1920x1080 -b:v 3842k -ac 2 -r 29.97 -c:v libx264 -ar 44100 -b:a 140k -c:a aac -aspect 16:9 -vf "subtitles='C:\Users\wwy12⁠\Downloads\subtitle.srt':charenc=cp936:force_style='PrimaryColour=&H0000FFFF,OutlineColour=&H00FFFFFF'" "c:\ffoutput\out.mp4" -y`

and here is the output:

```
ffmpeg version N-82759-g1f5630a-Sherpya Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.2.1 (GCC) 20161118
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\wwy12\Downloads\RaymondChen20_high.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : One Dev Question with Raymond Chen - How do program settings work in virtual desktops
    album           : One Dev Question with Raymond Chen - How do program settings work in virtual desktops
    encoder         : Lavf57.10.101
    comment         : Application Development, C#, C++, developer center, Developer Tools, Developer Resources, Developers, Development, Windows 10
    copyright       : 2017 Microsoft Corporation
  Duration: 00:01:04.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3985 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 3842 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 140 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[subtitles @ 00000000030af220] Unable to parse option value "Userswwy12Downloadssubtitle.srt" as image size
    Last message repeated 1 times
[subtitles @ 00000000030af220] Error setting option original_size to value Userswwy12Downloadssubtitle.srt.
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 00000000030af160] Error applying options to the filter.
```

Here’s [a screen shot of the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTEvr.png)
(some people might find it easier to read).

Answer (score 3):

The

```
Unable to parse option value "Userswwy12Downloadssubtitle.srt" …
```

error message
reveals that FFmpeg is discarding the backslashes in the filename. 
[This Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/718027/150988) suggests
that you may be able to replace the backslashes (`\`)
with ordinary, forward slashed (`/`); i.e., something like

```
-vf "subtitles='C:/Users/wwy12/Downloads/subtitle.srt'…
```

and if you’re running on drive `C:`, try leaving `C:` out of the filename.

My first thought when I saw this
was that FFmpeg was using backslash as an escape character. 
The normal fix for that situation is to double up on the backslashes:

```
-vf "subtitles='C:\\Users\\wwy12\\Downloads\\subtitle.srt'…
```

but [this FFmpeg trouble ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3334) suggests
that you may need to *quadruple* them. 
(This is not totally unreasonable;
I have sometimes needed to use ridiculous numbers of backslashes un Unix.) 
So you might need to do something like

```
-vf "subtitles='C\\:\\\\Users\\\\wwy12\\\\Downloads\\\\subtitle.srt'…
```

I don’t understand why they suggest putting backslashes before the colon (`:`). 
As I said, you might be able to make your life simpler by omitting the `C:`.

**Update:**

The OP reported that he got it to work
by doubling the backslashes in the `subtitles` path
and adding one before the colon:

```
-vf "subtitles='C\:\\Users\\wwy12\\Downloads\\subtitle.srt'…
```

Comment: The third code block in your answer is what has worked for me on Win 7/cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Replace -vf with -filter_complex. And for the unable to parse error replace the black slashes[] with front slashes[/] and most importantly put a back slash after (C:/Users).

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\USER\Downloads\output.mp4 -filter_complex "subtitles='C\:/Users/USER/Downloads/subtitle.srt'" C:\Users\USER\Downloads\foutput.mp4
```